# Frame height not working for Navigation Link in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, frame, apple-watch

I'm trying to resize a Navigation Link to accommodate several Links in a Navigation Stack. The frame width works, but the frame height doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried putting the frame config in different area without success.

Here's my code:
`import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack{
        Text("Game Logger")
            .padding(.top,0)
        VStack{
            NavigationLink {
                GameView()
            }label: {
                VStack {
                    Label("Start Game", systemImage: "")
                        .dynamicTypeSize(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.xSmall/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .font(.callout)
                }
                .controlSize(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.mini/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding(.top, 0)
            }
            .frame(width: 100)
            .frame(height: 20)
            NavigationLink {
                LiveStatisticsView()
            }label: {
                VStack {
                    Label("Live Statistics", systemImage: "")
                        .dynamicTypeSize(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.xSmall/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .font(.callout)
                }
                .frame( width: 100, height: 5)
                //.border(Color.blue, width: 2)
                .padding(.top, 0)
            }
            NavigationLink {
                StatisticsView()
            }label: {
                VStack {
                    Label("Statistics", systemImage: "")
                    .dynamicTypeSize(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.xSmall/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.callout)
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 20)
                .padding(.top, 0)
            }
            NavigationLink {
                UtilitiesView()
            }label: {
                VStack {
                    Label("Utilities", systemImage: "")
                        .dynamicTypeSize(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.xSmall/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .font(.callout)
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 0)
                .padding(.top, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
[Screenshot of display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnrQ5.png)`

As can be seen in the screenshot, the width is working, but the height isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you views inside of VStack, because currently your text and VStack doesn't look in right relation between each other. Maybe it will help.

```
NavigationStack {
         VStack(spacing: .zero) {
                Text("Game Logger")
                    .padding(.top,0)
                VStack{...}
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the VStack that's not adjusting the frame height is in the first Navigation Link, do that doesn't help.